# Validate input filed without form

Tags: form-validation

I really need to have custom or even magento validation for my input field.

**Problem is, there is no form in my field, there is only input field.**

```
<input id="item_custom_payment_" name="pay_part_payment" value="" style="" class="input-text item-price validate-greater-than-zero">
<button .... >Submit</button> //calling custom controller action
```

For example: Comment section in order view page in admin area.

This `var customForm = new VarienForm('custom_form');` doesn't work because there is no `<form>` in my section.

Is there anyway around to validate the input field?

**UPDATE**

My button looks like this:

```
<button id="id_5bb6f3992cb320bf703ed93f702dd64a" title="Submit Paid Amount" type="button" class="scalable save paid-amount" onclick="submitAndReloadArea($('order_paid_block_wrap').parentNode, '[admin_url]'); javascript:reload(); return true" style=""><span><span><span>Submit Paid Amount</span></span></span></button>
```

Comment: You can validate input field using jquery

Answer (score 7):

You can **validate individual field** like below

```
Validation.validate($('your-element-id'));
```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679859/magento-validate-form-only-certain-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input id="item_custom_payment" name="pay_part_payment" value="" style="" class="input-text">
<div style="display: none;" id="validation_item_custom_payment" class="validation-advice">This is a required field.</div>

<button id="id_5bb6f3992cb320bf703ed93f702dd64a" title="Submit Paid Amount" type="button" class="scalable save paid-amount" onclick="submitAndReloadArea($('order_paid_block_wrap').parentNode, '[admin_url]'); javascript:reload(); return true" style=""><span><span><span>Submit Paid Amount</span></span></span></button>

<script>
function submitAndReloadArea() {
    var itemCustomPayment = $('item_custom_payment').value;
    if(itemCustomPayment=='') {
        $('validation_item_custom_payment').show();
        return false;
    }else {
       $('validation_item_custom_payment').hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will work, however there is "submitAndReloadArea" function called too. Is there a way to prevent? I was looking for more like magento way of doing this btw.

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: Or Can you share submitAndReloadArea() code?

Comment: `submitAndReloadArea()` is magento core function. So there is nothing we can put inside `if(validation)`.

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: This wont work.

Comment: If my ans help full  then ass & vote

Answer (score 0):

If your input isn't inside any other form you just can wrap it with a new `<form>`, then you'll be able to use `VarienForm` for validation.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work with JQuery for me, but worked with Javascript instead.

Example:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="required-entry input-text" name="medium-description" id="medium-description" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

isMediumDescriptionValid = Validation.validate(document.getElementById('medium-description'))

if(isMediumDescriptionValid){
  //success action
}else{
  //failure action
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i validated input fields without form tag. This is working solution.

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="first" class="bk-firstname" id="bk-firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required="true" > 
                   
<input type="text" name="last" class="bk-lastname" id="bk-lastname" placeholder="Lastname" required="true" >
<input type="text" name="email" email="bk-email" id="bk-email" placeholder="email address" required="true" >
<button id="booking_form_submit" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</div>

$('#booking_form_submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var flag = [];
        // must be in reverse order to show html5 validation message in right order
            flag[0] = document.getElementById("bk-email").reportValidity();
            flag[1] = document.getElementById("bk-lastname").reportValidity(); 
            flag[2] = document.getElementById("bk-firstname").reportValidity();
            
            if(flag.every(Boolean)){.  // true if all elements in flag array are true
                // submit form
                /// Your logic here
                console.log('submit');
            }
          
           
            
            

        });
```